# Azure Function Host key limit?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

The Azure Function documentation is clear on using Host and/or Function keys to provide "api key" authorization.  However, I can't find anything that indicates if there is a limit on how many keys can be created on a particular function or function app.

I would like to share a unique key with each tenant in a multi-tenant application so I can update or revoke them on a per-tenant basis.  However, this approach will only work if I am able to generate hundreds (or potentially thousands) of keys.

Can anyone confirm any known limits on the number of keys that can be generated on a function app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There aren't any strict limits imposed by the runtime, but we can't make any guarantees that this would be performant at scale.